# Run script watch on latest version of webpack - Invalid configuration object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, devtools

when running this command

```
npm run-script watch
```

i have this error

```
npm ERR! command sh -c webpack --watch -d --output ./target/classes/static/built/bundle.js
```

And this one

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$".
   BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict.
   Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.
```

My webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/App.js',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Any idea why?

using

"webpack": "^5.25.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is written in your error. You have to *specify* value for "devtool". If you want to use flag [`-d` (short for `--devtool`)](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#flags), you have to indicate it's value: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool

Comment: i tried this devtool: 'sourcemaps', but it did not help, any dea how I should it?

Comment: Check list of possible values in second link. There is no "sourcemaps", but there is "source-map"

Comment: still not working with: devtool: 'source-map',

Comment: Where are you putting this value? In config or in command line? If you setting this value in config, you should remove `-d` flag in CLI command you  are executing. You are calling " webpack --watch **-d** --output ./target/classes/static/built/bundle.js" and it should be " webpack --watch **-d source-map** --output ./target/classes/static/built/bundle.js"

Comment: i am running this in command line : npm run-script watch, in package.json     "watch": "webpack --watch -d source-map --output ./target/classes/static/built/bundle.js"  --> error : [webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--output'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options

Comment: This is already different error. You should read [documentation for weebpack-cli](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/) yourself and write proper command by hand

Comment: thanks, it works now by putting this --> "watch": "webpack -w -d eval-source-map -o static/built/bundle.js"